# Connecting C# application to a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

I created a SQL Server database and tried to connect it to the application but it's not showing any errors neither the password and username I entered are correct or no

I tried using multiple baths as well but still have the same problem, does and one know how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=yes;Integrated Security=True;");

        try
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();

            String query = ("SELECT * FROM yesno WHERE username = @UserName AND password = @Password") ;

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Password);

            int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count == 1)
            {
                //MainWindow dashboard = new MainWindow();
                //this.Close();
                //dashboard.Show();
                MessageBox.Show("Yes");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope your *not* storing plain text passwords like your code above implies and you are, infact, somehow salting and hashing it.

Comment: Form the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) of ExecuteScalar: "Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query". You seem to assume however to get the number of rows matching a condition, right? This would be  `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`.

Comment: Side note: use a `using` to dispose the connection, command and reader, instead of a `finally`

Answer (score 0):

Initial catalog property is a name of concrete database you want to connect on localhost. Your database is named "yes"?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/understanding-8220-data-source-local-8221-in-sql-server/ba-p/383478

Comment: yes I named my database "yes" just to test it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).